# how to set default value of spin editor aspx devexpress

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, reporting, default-value

I have a report and data filtering using `aspx` (`DevExpress` component) `SpinEditor`. So the main problem is that I don't want the default value of `SpinEditor` to be equal to 0.

I want to set it in such a way to make visible all the records of the report. When I have default value set to 0 no record is visible, because all the records are depended on the filtering using this `SpinEditors`. Please, let me know if it's posiible and if it is, then how?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you set the "value" property? Then that is your default value. So just type:

```
spinedit1.value = 50;
```

So it will show you 50 records. I hope I understand you right.

Comment: Not quetly right Alex. In this SpinEdit I don't have number of records on the page. I have in this SpinEdit ID, Name a ns os on and filter my data in such a way. So, by default no record appears, util I set values in SpinEdit. So I was interested if it's possible to make it in such a way, that before sorting data all my records appear.